# Intellij nao reconhece o Lombok

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, intellij, lombok

Estou com um problema ao usar o Intellij IDEA 2020.3.2. Eu estou usando o lombok no meu projeto spring da seguinte forma:

pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
       <lombok.version>1.18.16</lombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                </exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Com meu compiler configurado da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E com o seguinte plugin do lombok:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem quando vou tentar dar um build na minha aplicacao utilizando o:

```
clean install
```

Ele da o seguinte erro:

```
cannot find symbol
```

Em um getId() do lombok. Por favor alguem pode me ajudar? Eu nao consigo desinstalar o plugin porque nao tem a opcao la. Ja nao sei mais oque fazer

Comment: Atualize a pergunta com o código do POJO. `mvn clean install` na linha de comando funciona? Já tentou atualizar para o Lombok 1.18.18? Já tentou reimportar o projeto do Maven? Já tentou resetar o IDE e limpar o cache? (Só estou dando algumas opções).

Comment: Por sinal, você pode desinstalar o plugin em `File > Settings > Plugins`.

Comment: Baixa o .jar do lombok e importa ele no IntelliJ: https://projectlombok.org/ Tive esse problema na versao 2020 do IntelliJ, nas versoes mais atuais nao tive.